# Replace custom tags in html with Java

Tags: java, html, templates, replace

is there a library on Java to help me to achieve custom tags replacement in html

like for example here is a simple template :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <p>$welcome_title</p>
    <p>$email_body</p>
    <p>$footer_text</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can i replace this custom tags ($welcome_title,$email_body,$footer_text) with values from java ?

The idea is to have template with tags which can be replaced at runtime with values from java objects :)

Also maybe (if there is a library) to generate straight away from html an PDF doc

Thanks :)

Comment: You could use Freemarker ( https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_template.html ). Or if you got such a simple use case like in your example code, maybe `String.replace` is enough. Another alternative would be to use jsoup to traverse the HTML elements an look for matching variable strings.

Comment: @BenjaminM, thanks for idea man . well I have provided a simple use case, but the real case scenario is with a very huge HTML with a lot of data to be replaced. I'll take a look at Freemaker

Answer (score 0):

In Java world you can use https://www.thymeleaf.org/ or https://freemarker.apache.org/

Comment: @lepilov Please don't share links to the external sites. Add some context and show how your solution can solve the problem.

Comment: @ilepilov, thanks man :) Indeed i'll go with freemarker I think, thanks a lot !